# C# returning List<Object> from DLL

Tags: c#, dll

My dll have a method. This method have to return some data which are represented with class. I try to return this data with List<> but it not work.I get error that: The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add reference to assembly. My dll like this:

```
public class CLASSA{
    public List<CLASSB> function(){

    }
}
```

And Main will be like this:

```
void functionMainn(){
CLASSA cls;
gridView.DataSource = cls.function();
}
```

How can I fix it or return these values as data source of gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says; to utilize a type returned by DLL A but defined in DLL B you need a reference to **both** A and B. Add those references and it will work fine.

Also, make sure to instantiate `cls` before using it.